# LINQ include doesn't include related entities when parameters are passed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-4

I have the following code. When I don't give the param "current" and "version" so it only run the first line, the lstFile variable at the end contains the file with it's related jobs. If a give the "current" parameter or the "version" parameter, files are returned without the related Jobs. But since I include the Jobs in the first step, why does the related Jobs are lost in the process?

And by the way, lazy loading is Off, that's why I need to do the include.

```
IQueryable<File> filteredFiles = entities.Files.Include("Jobs");

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(current))
{
    bool bActive = current == "1" ? true : false;

    filteredFiles =
        from f in filteredFiles
        join j in entities.Jobs
            on f.IDFile equals j.IDFile
        where j.Active == bActive
        select f;
}

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version))
{
    filteredFiles =
        from f in filteredFiles
            join j in entities.Jobs
            on f.IDFile equals j.IDFile
        where j.Version == version
        select f;
}

List<File> lstFile = filteredFiles.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: have you tried adding the include _after_ the two `if` blocks?

Comment: it can't be done because the Include function is only available from entities.Files collection directly. After this point, I'm working with a IQueryable collection which doesn't have this function available.

Comment: Isn't there also an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220202(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I'm using entity framework 4.0 so I don't think it's available.

Comment: I see. What is the runtime type of the filteredFiles after the two if blocks? I ask because maybe you can cast (`((QueryObject<Files>)filteredFiles).Include`).

Comment: The runtime type is: {System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<namespace.fms.File>}

Comment: good, you should be able to cast then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Eren Ersönmez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201088/eren-ers%C3%B6nmez) point me out that there was an `Include` function for the `IQueryable` interface, I decided to try to upgrade my EF4 to EF6 and with this update, the function was available! This is not clear in the documentation from Microsoft.

If that can help someone else, I have followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx) on how to update from EF4 to EF6.

Answer (score 0):

The `Include` merely means that the `Jobs` property isn't going to defer execution when the query is executed and that each record is going to also return all of the related `Jobs` records.  In your joins you're actually filtering out the files that don't have jobs that meet the given criteria.  You aren't filtering out the jobs of those files, you're filtering out all of the files that have those jobs.  The `Include` won't prevent those files from being filtered out.

Comment: How should I do my filter on the active/version? Since I'm new to linq, maybe my 2 queries aren't good. My goal is to select the files that contains jobs with these parameters.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté And you're doing just that.

Comment: ok, and the results seems good except that they doesn't have the related Jobs loaded. Why? For example, it return 3 files (which have 3 jobs each) but they are not loaded.